# WMIPRVSE needs to be run under network services by default

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, user-permissions, wmi-service

I have 2 separate servers (windows server 2008 r2) from where I am running vbs scripts through a microsoft scheduler ( my-computer>manager>Schedule). when I run vbs scripts locally they are working fine, but when it is being run through scheduler one of servers is getting stacked. while the other is working fine. And also I have noticed from task manager that the working server runs the   WMIPRVSE.exe though Network Service user and the other one shows SERVICES as user.

How to make sure that  WMIPRVSE.exe will always run under Network Services. Thanks

**Edit:**

I have tried to change the log on user from services, but it failed to start the service than.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things I have tried, but I don't know which one helped me.
What I did is I granted all permissions to wscript file which is located in system32 somewhere, and after some time it became Network Servies. Again not really sure whether it was  because of  that change or other thing.